# python test string escaped chars still exist after printing

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, pytest

i have a function that does something like

```
def foo():
    return ["echo", "-e", "this\nis\nmultiline"]
```

this is written to a .sh file to be executed at some point and i would like to do a unitest to check that the string still has the `\n` in the last argument, and that it hasn't been written as

```
echo -e this
is
multiline
```

I don't know how to evaluate the string so that i get the post-print representation.

i know i could write it out, read it and check if it's correct, but it seems like unitesting really doesn't like that approach.

what would be the way of doing this?  (using python 2.7, preferably)

Comment: `os.popen(["/bin/echo", "-e", "this\nis\nmultiline"]).read()`? will let you check the output

Comment: the command will not necesarily be an echo command. So kinda? but not really.

it does bring the idea of just printing it and capturing the stream. But that doesn't sound too right either

Comment: I already made this unittest demo with python 3.8, hopefully it will helps you https://github.com/IT-Support-L2/Unit_TestDemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use string's function `splitlines`

```
a = "1\n2\n3"
b = r"1\n2\n3"
c = "1\\n2\\n3"

len(a.splitlines()) # 3
len(b.splitlines()) # 1
len(c.splitlines()) # 1
```